# Default Keyboard brightness is not working

Tags: 13.04, keyboard, brightness, asus, backlight

I am running Ubuntu 13.04 64-bit on an Asus UX31A. To control the default screen and keyboard brightness after the start, I wrote this to the rc.local:

```
echo 0 > /sys/class/backlight/acpi_video0/brightness
#echo 0 > /sys/devices/platform/asus-nb-wmi/leds/asus::kbd_backlight/brightness
exit 0
```

The screen brightness is perfectly adjusted after every restart, but the keyboard backlight won't work. It's always at 100% and if I uncomment the second line the screen brightness won't work, too. Seems like the permission is denied or the script can't access the file, because the path is totally correct.

Any tips?

Comment: Tried kernel boot parameters like `acpi_osi='!Windows 2012'`, `acpi_osi=Linux`, `acpi_osi=`, and/or `acpi_backlight=vendor`?

Comment: Well, atleast one:
`GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash pcie_aspm=force drm.vblankoffdelay=1 i915.semaphores=1 acpi_osi='!Windows 2012'"` 
Should I try the others, too?

Comment: Any 1 of the 4 i listed the last one can be combined with the 1st 3, for the most part this is trail and error, don't forget to run update-grub after making the change, reboot should be obvious

Comment: Nope, none of them worked for me. I tried some combinations but without success. Maybe one entry like `drm.vblankoffdelay=1 i915.semaphores=1` is the problem?